# Should I need a paid Apple ID to build iOS .ipa from Expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo, apple-id

I'm developing a Mobile Application using React Native and Expo. I built the `.apk` by running `exp build:android` .

BTW, is it possible to build the `.ipa` by running `exp build:ios` ? I have an UNPAID Apple ID. I don't want to publish this in Apple Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Paid Apple Developer Account, you can...

- run/debug app on actual DEVICE
- publish app on the App Store or test flight user
- implement the capabilities which can be used on the iPhone/iPad, etc.

With out Paid Apple Developer Account, you can...

- run app in simulator but CAN'T run it on actual DEVICE
- not create an `.ipa` file
- not able to publish the app to the App Store/Testflight, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer!! This is the answer what I was looking for :-)

Comment: You can run apps on an a device with a free account but the number of devices you can deploy to, the number of apps you can deploy and the time that the deployment is valid for are all limited

Comment: Yes, true. but we can not create an `.ipa` with out paid apple developer account.